# What is the remainder when $(2^n+1)$ is divided by $(16^{2015}+1)$?

Tags: number-theory

> If $n = 2^{2016}+73$, what is the remainder when $(2^n+1)$ is divided by $(16^{2015}+1)$?

We have $16^{2015}+1 = 2^{8060}+1$. Thus, we need to find $m,r$ where $8060m+r = 2^{2016}+73$ and $0 \leq r < 8060$. This doesn't seem easy, so I was wondering if there was an easier way of solving this question?

Comment: Let $m=16^{2015}+1 = 2^{8060}+1$. Working $\!\!\pmod{m}$, we have $2^{8060}\equiv -1$. 
Additionally, $8060=2^2\cdot 5\cdot 13\cdot 31$. It follows that we may compute $2^{2016}+73\pmod{8060}$ by carefully exploiting the CRT. If I am not wrong, we have $2^{2016}+73\equiv 5469\pmod{8060}$, hence:
$$ 2^n = 2^{8060k+5469}\equiv (-1)^k 2^{5469}\pmod{m} $$
and since $k$ is odd, $2^n\equiv \color{red}{-2^{5469}}\pmod{m}.$

Comment: (moved to comments due to a (?) revenge downvote)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is it possible to find the positive remainder here?

Comment: I guess it is $m-2^{5469}$.